Is there any ways to align row without conditional paddings?
I have this widgets in a row and I want to align it without conditional paddings and make Sized. box more close to the start if divider. How can I do this?
Now conditional paddings are not working well on different screen sizes and UI is messy for screen sizes smaller.
Here is my code and what i expected to get from design:  
Code:
class PremiumPlanItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const PremiumPlanItem({this.isYear = true, super.key});

  final bool isYear;
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Color baseTextColor = context.colors.premiumSubsSelectText;
    final TextStyle baseStyle = context.primaryFonts.regular14.copyWith(
      color: baseTextColor,
    );

    return RowExt(
      padding: Pad(
        bottom: Sizes.s12,
        top: Sizes.s20,
      ),
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: ColumnExt(
            padding: Pad(
              left: Sizes.s12,
            ),
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                        
                              SizedBox.square(
                                dimension: 16,
                                child: DecoratedBox(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    gradient: [Colors.red, Colors.blue],
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              TextExt(
                                padding: Pad(left: Sizes.s8),
                                isYear ? "Annual" : 'Month',
                                style: context.primaryFonts.medium15.copyWith(
                                  color: context.colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              if (isYear) Text('test text'),

                              TextExt(
                                padding: isYear ? Pad(left: Sizes.s44) : Pad(left: Sizes.s94),
                                '123',
                                style: context.primaryFonts.regular15.copyWith(
                                  color: baseTextColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          if (isYear)
                            RowExt(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              padding: Pad(
                                top: Sizes.s4,
                              ),
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                 'test text'
                                  style: context.primaryFonts.regular15.copyWith(
                                    color: context.colors.white,
                                    decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '  test text',
                                  style: baseStyle,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Since I need the text to be on one line, because of the widget that displays not an annual subscription but a monthly one, I cannot set the text on the same level and I have to use conditions for padding.

You can use ListTile widget, it has everything you need. Please find below code to achieve similar to what you want:
ListTile(
    title: Text('Annual'),
    subtitle: Text('Test Test'),
    leading: CircleAvatar(radius: 16, backgroundColor: Colors.grey),
    trailing: Text('Test text on same line'),
),

You can add text styling and dividers on top of it.
